# Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution (the multiplier $\beta$)

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature

$$d\log W=-\beta dQ \tag{1}$$
$$\beta=-\frac{1}{kT} \tag{2}$$

How do we get this result (2) from equation(1) ?

Comment: Purely using equation 1 you clearly can't. How much of the rest of Stat Mech are you assuming has already been derived?

Comment: Very naively one could say that in classical physics entropy is define as $dS = dQ/T$ on a process, and Boltzmann's relation is $S=k_B \log{W}$, hence the result is straightforward. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: In fact, the value of the entropy is found from the equation after compensation for the beta value